# Symfony3 Select item or add new and reload form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, symfony

I'm building an Symfony3 form, where I have 5 entities:
Application, ApplicationItem, Survey, Supplier, SupplierItem.

Relations is:

**OneToOne:** Application - Survey;

**OneToMany:** Application - ApplicationItem; Survey - Supplier; Supplier - SupplierItem; Survey - SupplierItem;

**ManyToMany:** ApplicationItem - SupplierItem;

I created all kinds of formTypes.

In **application** form we fill the **title**, **date** and add **applicationItems** with **titles** and **quantities**.

Then we create a **survey** where we select an **application** by dropdown and have to select (probably select2 box) or add **suppliers**. And then in the same form we have to create some SupplierItems with titles **and the prices, related to the Suppliers and ApplicationItems, how to do that?**

[image]

Comment: this is a question with tons of solutions. Some hints:
You can build multiple forms on one page. 
You can use a custom data object for a form that holds data for multiple entities or actions after submit. You can use unmapped fields, for example buttons that might fire some javascript. In Symfony you can also use childforms into the main form and even make form collections. http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html

Comment: This question is way too broad.